# PHP - preg_replace() pattern not work correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex in my php class to remove some unwanted chars from a remote file.
I have the problem that the regex will not work at all, I've noticed that the chars are still present in some point of the parsed file.

**Here is a the part of the file that will not be parsed (it's part of an Array)**

```
"||clickbank.net/*offer_id=$popup,third-party"
"! IP addresses"
"||130.211.$popup,third-party,domain=~in-addr.arpa"
"||142.91.$popup,third-party,domain=~in-addr.arpa"
"||185.147.34.126^$popup,third-party"
"||216.21.13.$popup,domain=~in-addr.arpa"
"||35.232.188.118^$popup"
"||5.45.79.15^$popup"
"! IP Regex (commonly used, hax'd IP addresses)"
"/^https?:\/\/(35|104)\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\//$popup,third-party"
""
```

**This is the expected output is**

```
"*://*.clickbank.net/*"
"://130.211.*/*"
"://142.91.*/*"
"://185.147.34.126/*"
"://216.21.13/*"
"://35.232.188.118/*"
"*://5.45.79.15/*"
```

This is the code:

```
  private static function parseFilterLists( $filters )
  {
    foreach( $filters as $filter ){
      $file =  file_get_contents( $filter );
      self::$parsed = preg_replace( '/\!.*/', '', $file );
      self::$parsed = preg_replace( '/\|\|([^\^\$=,]+).*/', '*://*.$1/*', $file ); 
    }
    
    return explode( "\n", self::$parsed );
  }
```

The line I want to remove have the `!` char at the beginning, I also need to remove the last two lines from the array because one is empty and another is a regex pattern but it's not required for my scope.
Other lines that have the `!` char are correctly processed from the function using `preg_replace()` and are removed.

Also when the method of the class is parsing the input file, there are some lines that will not be processed correctly, for example this input line `||clickbank.net/offer_id"` is suposed to become `"*://*.clickbank.net/*"` but will be processed and returned in this way `"*://*.clickbank.net/*offer_id/*"`

How I can fix this?

Comment: Please, don't post image, just put the text before **and** after.

Comment: `([^\^\$=,]+)` matches any character that is not `^` or `$` or `=` or `,` so it matches `clickbank.net/offer_id"` in group 1.

Comment: ok, but with the other lines the replacement works fine with this rule, if I remove `^` the output will not be formatted as expected. How I can solve the two problems?

Comment: We can't answer without example file **and** expected result, text, not image.

Comment: @Toto the expected output is already in the question `"*://*.clickbank.net/*"`. I will update the question to add the text needed.

Comment: Please provide a list of sample input strings that you want to convert, so we can compare it properly to your expected output.

Comment: @BadHorsie see the updated question

Comment: @Toto see the updated question

Comment: Can you provide more context? Please show what your file content looks like, and how you are parsing it through the function.

Comment: @BadHorsie I think that the function code is clear and show how the files are parsed. For the original files take a look to these two links:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/easylist/easylist/master/easylist/easylist_adservers_popup.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/easylist/easylist/master/easylist/easylist_adservers.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
self::$parsed = preg_replace( '/\|\|([^\^\$=,]+).*/', '*://*.$1/*', $file );
```

doesn't work as you think it does.

- `([^\^\$=,]+)` stores in group 1 1 or more any character that is not `^`, `$`, `=` or `,`. So, appoied to `clickbank.net/offer_id"` group 1 will contain tyhe whole match: `clickbank.net/offer_id"`.

Use this instead:

```
self::$parsed = preg_replace('~\|\|([^/^$]+).*~', '*://*.$1/*', $file );
```

Moreover, your two lines of code are replacing the same string `$file` and store the result in `$parse` so the first replacement is lost, you have to do the second replacement on the result of the first replacement, like:

```
self::$parsed = preg_replace( '/!.*/', '', $file );
self::$parsed = preg_replace( '~\|\|([^/^$]+).*~', '*://*.$1/*', self::$parsed );
```

Comment: @miko: Your actual regex should work, just remove the escape before `!`. A question: are the quotes part of the strings?

Comment: Tested your pattern, but with it I get an empty array after the file processing.

Comment: The example code is part of the output array and are not part of the strings that are parsed from the method

Comment: removing the escape before the `!` isn't solving the problem, tested now and the lines with it are still there

Comment: I'll see it, but I can't apply the pattern to replace the old one because this will give me a blank array as output. Also the `!`comment lines are still available

Comment: to have a more clear idea of the input file you can take a look at these two links that are the original files before begin parsed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/easylist/easylist/master/easylist/easylist_adservers_popup.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/easylist/easylist/master/easylist/easylist_adservers.txt

Comment: I've modified the processed file into the second `preg_replace()` and now the unwanted lines are removed, The only thing that isn't working for me is this pattern `~\|\|([^/^$]+).*~` that will result in an empty array. Last thing I need to do is to remove the empty entries from the result array.